# gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-|’

Tags: gcc, command-line

While I try to install `dso` package (https://github.com/brendenpetersen/deep-symbolic-optimization), I get this error :

MY COMMAND:

```
pip install -e ./dso[all]
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
Obtaining file:///home/remi/deep-symbolic-optimization-master/dso
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pytest in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (7.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (0.29.30)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<=1.19 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow==1.14 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numba==0.53.1 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (0.53.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (1.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (8.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: deap in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pathos in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (0.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: progress in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (4.64.0)
Requirement already satisfied: commentjson in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mpi4py in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pybullet in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (3.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: gym[box2d]==0.15.4 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (0.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: stable-baselines[mpi]==2.10.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from dso==1.0.dev0) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle~=1.2.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (4.6.0.66)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: box2d-py~=2.3.5 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (2.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite<0.37,>=0.36.0rc1 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from numba==0.53.1->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.36.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from numba==0.53.1->dso==1.0.dev0) (59.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from stable-baselines[mpi]==2.10.0->dso==1.0.dev0) (3.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from stable-baselines[mpi]==2.10.0->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<1.15.0rc0,>=1.14.0rc0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (3.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.47.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.37.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from click->dso==1.0.dev0) (4.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: lark-parser<0.8.0,>=0.7.1 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from commentjson->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.7.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas->dso==1.0.dev0) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas->dso==1.0.dev0) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pox>=0.3.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pathos->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: multiprocess>=0.70.12 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pathos->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.70.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: dill>=0.3.4 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pathos->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: ppft>=1.6.6.4 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pathos->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.6.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tomli>=1.0.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest->dso==1.0.dev0) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: iniconfig in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.8.2 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest->dso==1.0.dev0) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<2.0,>=0.12 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn->dso==1.0.dev0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sympy->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tqdm->dso==1.0.dev0) (5.4.0)
WARNING: gym 0.15.4 does not provide the extra 'classic-control'
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: atari-py~=0.2.0 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click->dso==1.0.dev0) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click->dso==1.0.dev0) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib->stable-baselines[mpi]==2.10.0->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib->stable-baselines[mpi]==2.10.0->dso==1.0.dev0) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib->stable-baselines[mpi]==2.10.0->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0->gym[box2d]==0.15.4->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (3.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from werkzeug>=0.11.15->tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property in /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from h5py->keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow==1.14->dso==1.0.dev0) (1.5.2)
Installing collected packages: dso
  Running setup.py develop for dso
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/bin/python3.6 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/remi/deep-symbolic-optimization-master/dso/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/remi/deep-symbolic-optimization-master/dso/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
         cwd: /home/remi/deep-symbolic-optimization-master/dso/
    Complete output (19 lines):
    running develop
    running egg_info
    writing dso.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to dso.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to dso.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to dso.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'dso.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'dso.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'dso.cyfunc' extension
    gcc -pthread -B /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -| /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -fPIC -I/home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/include/python3.6m -I/home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/include/python3.6m -c dso/cyfunc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/dso/cyfunc.o
    gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-|’
    /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:493: UserWarning: Normalizing '1.0dev' to '1.0.dev0'
      warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
    /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:159: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      EasyInstallDeprecationWarning,
    /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/remi/anaconda3/envs/DSO_env/bin/python3.6 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/remi/deep-symbolic-optimization-master/dso/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/remi/deep-symbolic-optimization-master/dso/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am a complete noob in computer science, so the only thing I get is that it fails due to gcc not recognizing the command `-|` as stated by this line in the error message:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-|’
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Thanks and regards,
Rémi

Answer (score 0):

just reading the command that fails, it seems there's a | (pipe) instead of a I (capital i).
I'm not sure if you've entered a | somewhere in your configuration?

Comment: Currently this reads like a comment on your impression that there is a typo. For that you would need the commenting privilege, which you do not yet have. If you cannot [edit] this into an actual answer according to [answer] please delete this. One way to turn this into an answer is ...

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."